# An issue with changing the camera.CFrame when using a custom starter character and in VR

Tags: lua, roblox

heres my code:

```
local VRService = game:GetService("VRService")
local UIS = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local camera = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer

local min = 0.2
local speed = 0.2
local rotationSpeed = 0.5

local function onInputChanged(input, _gameProcessed)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Thumbstick1 then
        local thumbstickValue = input.Position
        if thumbstickValue.Y > min then
            print("up")
            camera.CFrame = CFrame.new(camera.CFrame.Position.X, camera.CFrame.Position.Y + speed, camera.CFrame.Position.Z)
        end

        if thumbstickValue.Y < -min then
            print("down")
            camera.CFrame = CFrame.new(camera.CFrame.Position.X, camera.CFrame.Position.Y - speed, camera.CFrame.Position.Z)
        end
    end

    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.Thumbstick2 then
        local thumbstickValue = input.Position
        -- Handle thumbstick2 for smooth camera rotation here if needed
    end
end

local function onInputBegan(input, _gameProcessed)
    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.ButtonL1 then
        print("leftGRIP")
        -- Add code here to perform actions when the left grip button is pressed
    end

    if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.ButtonR1 then
        print("rightGRIP")
        -- Add code here to perform actions when the right grip button is pressed
    end
end

UIS.InputBegan:Connect(onInputBegan)
UIS.InputChanged:Connect(onInputChanged)
```

the issue is, in the "if input.KeyCode == Enum.KeyCode.THumnbStick1 then", when changing the camera.CFrame, instead of moving directly up, it moves forward, and slows, the farther the player gets from where they initially spawned.

the end goal for this script is a VR flying experience similar to that of "VR hands". Im simply trying to figure out how to move the Camera. The "head" part and "hands" parts are set to the camera's location with this separate script:

```
local VRService = game:GetService("VRService")
local player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
local camera = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera

local PlayerModule = require(game.Players.LocalPlayer.PlayerScripts:WaitForChild("PlayerModule"))


local Controls = PlayerModule:GetControls()

Controls:Disable()

camera.CFrame = CFrame.new(Vector3.new(0,10,0))

while wait() do
    local character = player.Character
    if character then
        if VRService.VREnabled == true then
            local headCFrame = camera.CFrame * VRService:GetUserCFrame(Enum.UserCFrame.Head)

            -- Get the local CFrames for Left and Right Hand
            local leftControllerCFrameLocal = VRService:GetUserCFrame(Enum.UserCFrame.LeftHand)
            local rightControllerCFrameLocal = VRService:GetUserCFrame(Enum.UserCFrame.RightHand)

            -- Apply rotation to the local CFrames
            local rotatedLeftCFrame = leftControllerCFrameLocal * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(-45), 0, 0)
            local rotatedRightCFrame = rightControllerCFrameLocal * CFrame.Angles(math.rad(-45), 0, 0)

            -- Apply offset locally to the rotated CFrames
            local offset = Vector3.new(0, 0.2, 0)
            local offsetLeftCFrame = rotatedLeftCFrame + rotatedLeftCFrame:vectorToWorldSpace(offset)
            local offsetRightCFrame = rotatedRightCFrame + rotatedRightCFrame:vectorToWorldSpace(offset)

            -- Convert local CFrames to world CFrames
            local leftControllerCFrame = camera.CFrame * offsetLeftCFrame
            local rightControllerCFrame = camera.CFrame * offsetRightCFrame

            player.Character.Head.CFrame = headCFrame
            player.Character.LeftHand.CFrame = leftControllerCFrame
            player.Character.RightHand.CFrame = rightControllerCFrame
        end
    end
end
```